# wifi is not working in my laptop in ubuntu but in windows it is working

Tags: wireless, acer, aspire

In my Acer aspire e 15 e5-573-5108 wifi is not working is their any solution...
this is my wireless-test-info

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 11 Sep 2015 23:21 IST +0530

Booted last: 11 Sep 2015 23:07 IST +0530

Script from: 30 Apr 2015 17:23 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.19.0-28-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 31 15:52:51 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:098a]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e09a]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:57cc Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0489:e09c Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

cfg80211              540672  0 
acer_wmi               20480  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  1 acer_wmi
video                  20480  2 i915,acer_wmi
wmi                    20480  1 acer_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e60:cff:feb6:65b2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:471957 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:430019 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:611087564 (611.0 MB)  TX bytes:38035008 (38.0 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:02:00.0/net/eth0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       eth0
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       e389a8e3-d67f-4a19-9da7-9d2c9c3dff16
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   e389a8e3-d67f-4a19-9da7-9d2c9c3dff16 | Wired connection 1
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         ip = 192.168.1.3/24, gw = 192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        expiry = 1442059673
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.3
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ip = fe80::2e60:cff:feb6:65b2/64, gw = ::

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/@RITESH@]] (600 root)
[connection] id=@RITESH@ | type=wifi
[wifi] ssid=@RITESH@ | mac-address=<MAC address>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-28-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     F28307769349A31F4B24FC2
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-28-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        99:11:2E:F1:A6:BA:85:BE:99:25:82:E9:FE:F3:A2:3F:1A:88:81:75
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# USB device 0x:0x (rt2800usb)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/663745/no-network-interface-atheros-168c0042-device-for-acer-in-15-04 Yours is the exact same device.

Comment: IMO it is far easier to purchase a linux compatible wireless usb card, you can get them for $10 . You can compile yourself - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1022411

Comment: There is a confirmed bug report for this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1436940

Comment: This wireless card is not yet supported. There are many other cards that are or do what bodhi said and get a supported USB device

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 Windows WiFi driver installation](/q/708061); the question currently linked as a duplicate relates to an Ethernet adapter, while OP's issue is with a Wifi adapter.

Comment: see also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/706581/no-wifi-in-ubuntu-15-04

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your BIOS settings to the defaults and saving the changes.

I had a similar problem, and was trying to reinstall my drivers, change something using terminal, but nothing worked, except the two steps. They are easy and fast, but may not necessarily solve your problem, just my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you check the physical wireless button on your computer are enable or not? Most of laptop have wireless indicator led, check if the led turn the light or not.
2. Try to enable the wireless from network panel

[image]