# No WiFi on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, lenovo

No WiFi option for Ubuntu 14.04 on my lenovo yoga 510 14SK laptop. I'm new to Ubuntu and can someone help me from the scratch?

Comment: If  you have windows installed, check if your WiFi adapter is ON in Windows.  Sometimes, that also is one of the major reasons why one is not able to connect to internet in Ubuntu OS.

Comment: First, you need to find out which network card you have with this command: lspci | awk '/[Nn]et/ {print $1}' | xargs -i% lspci -ks %

Comment: More often than not, the WiFi drivers are installed along with the Ubuntu OS. Check if you have a hard switch for WiFi on your laptop that's toggled Off.

Comment: i didnt have a hard switch @wave5459

Comment: @mAnN no i dont have dual boot..only ubuntu

Comment: i have Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042(rev 30)

Comment: 01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3850
 Kernel driver in use: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 30)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device 4035

Comment: ok. in that case we will look for other options.

Comment: i have done as @Jeremi31 have instructed https://askubuntu.com/questions/722061/qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-30-with-ubuntu-14-04-is-not-working . But still its not working

Comment: modprobe ath10k_pci
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ath10k_pci': Operation not permitted