# Wifi disabled on Lenovo V310 with Atheros [168c:0042] (rev 30) on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless, lenovo, atheros, ideapad

I've tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/706581/no-wifi-in-ubuntu-15-04) with no joy.

Anyone know what to do here?

wireless info

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 31 Jan 2017 18:39 EST -0500

Booted last: 31 Jan 2017 00:00 EST -0500

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-59-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 6 17:47:47 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:3820]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4035]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b57d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e360 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

ath10k_pci             45056  0
ath10k_core           229376  1 ath10k_pci
ath                    32768  1 ath10k_core
mac80211              643072  1 ath10k_core
cfg80211              565248  3 ath,mac80211,ath10k_core
compat                 16384  3 cfg80211,mac80211,ath10k_pci
ideapad_laptop         24576  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
wmi                    20480  1 ideapad_laptop
video                  40960  2 i915_bpo,ideapad_laptop

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:10.1.2.106  Bcast:10.1.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::97e4:3882:8211:af62/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9033 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6288 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4624574 (4.6 MB)  TX bytes:925890 (925.8 KB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp3s0' [IF2]>  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.1.1.5        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
10.1.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     100    0        0 enp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp2s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       909     1  0 18:13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp2s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       3645ceae-3107-3275-a8ac-4cbb7f73100c
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{3}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   3645ceae-3107-3275-a8ac-4cbb7f73100c | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.1.2.106/16
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.1.1.5
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.1.1.84
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 10.1.1.84
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 10.1.2.106
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 10.1.1.5
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        time_offset = -18000
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       broadcast_address = 10.1.255.255
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 529200
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       unknown_224 = FG200D4614811828
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 302400
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       routers = 10.1.1.5
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       expiry = 1486509228
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       tftp_server_name = http://modulis:Modulispw07@10.1.1.53/p
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       network_number = 10.1.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 604800
DHCP4.OPTION[32]:                       requested_host_name = 1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::97e4:3882:8211:af62/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Qualcomm Atheros
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         ath10k_pci
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.0-59-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp3s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:03:00.0/net/wlp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Robco_Lanex]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Robco_Lanex | type=wifi | permissions=user:robco:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Robco_Lanex
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Robco_Mesh]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Robco_Mesh | type=wifi | permissions=user:robco:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Robco_Mesh
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Robco_Mesh 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Robco_Mesh 1 | type=wifi | permissions=user:robco:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Robco_Mesh
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Toronto (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp2s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlp3s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

wlp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[ath10k_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-59-generic/updates/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_pci.ko
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-3.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware.bin
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Driver support for Atheros QCA988X PCIe devices
author:         Qualcomm Atheros
version:        backported from Linux (v4.4.2-0-g1cb8570) using backports v4.4.2-1-0-gbec4037
srcversion:     EBB3D4E36DE49B7EC8057D0
depends:        ath10k_core,compat
vermagic:       4.4.0-59-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           irq_mode:0: auto, 1: legacy, 2: msi (default: 0) (uint)
parm:           reset_mode:0: auto, 1: warm only (default: 0) (uint)

[ath10k_core]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-59-generic/updates/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_core.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Core module for QCA988X PCIe devices.
author:         Qualcomm Atheros
srcversion:     7994A4282CFF9CC0BA44367
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211,ath
vermagic:       4.4.0-59-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           debug_mask:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           uart_print:Uart target debugging (bool)
parm:           skip_otp:Skip otp failure for calibration in testmode (bool)
parm:           cryptmode:Crypto mode: 0-hardware, 1-software (uint)
parm:           rawmode:Use raw 802.11 frame datapath (bool)

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-59-generic/updates/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     6A988397A204F65CDF45A3C
depends:        cfg80211
vermagic:       4.4.0-59-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-59-generic/updates/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
version:        backported from Linux (v4.4.2-0-g1cb8570) using backports v4.4.2-1-0-gbec4037
srcversion:     E7DE97DC420ABD89A9888A8
depends:        cfg80211,compat
vermagic:       4.4.0-59-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-59-generic/updates/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
version:        backported from Linux (v4.4.2-0-g1cb8570) using backports v4.4.2-1-0-gbec4037
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     5C90ABE0CCC4BAA64E8582A
depends:        compat
vermagic:       4.4.0-59-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath10k_pci]
irq_mode: 0
reset_mode: 0

[ath10k_core]
cryptmode: 0
debug_mask: 0
rawmode: N
skip_otp: Y
uart_print: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

coretemp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf]
options ath10k_core skip_otp=y

[/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf]
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
blacklist acer_wmi

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    2.491159] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi interrupts 1 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    2.736245] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    4.099142] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[    4.115013] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down (repeated 2 times)
[    4.115131] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[    4.652183] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca9377 hw1.0 (0x05020000, 0x003820ff sub 17aa:4035) fw WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 fwapi 5 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features ignore-otp
[    4.652187] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 0 tracing 0 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    4.653310] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
[    4.653313] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    4.653315] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    4.653316] ath: Regpair used: 0x6c
[    4.661885] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[    4.686110] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[    7.407103] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
[    7.407112] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp2s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: I see I'm hard blocked but this machine has no WIFI switch and it's enabled in BIOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check if this fix will work for you. Terminal:

```
sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop
```

If that fixes WIFI, which it did for me. Make it permanent. Terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

At the bottom of the file, add the lines:

```
# Fix for WIFI hard block
blacklist ideapad_laptop
```

Comment: Welcom to Ask Ubuntu. It's always ok to answer your own question and sometimes one person finds an answer at more or less the same time that someone else does, so there's no problem there either. But rather than using the world 'solved' like a forum, you want to accept your answer. It may take a few hours before the system lets you do that.

Answer (score 1):

I would run this in terminal

```
echo "blacklist ideapad_laptop" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ideapad.conf
```

Reboot and see if wifi works

Then if wifi works post results for `sudo dmidecode | grep -i version` in case a kernel developer sees this