# Wifi signal very slow, works only for REALLY small distance

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, atheros

I am on ubuntu 16.04 and my wifi won't work if I am a little far from my router

My card is Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 (Lenovo G5070)

and here are my device settings:

```
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"ooredooE9BDC0"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: A4:B1:E9:E9:BD:C0   
          Bit Rate=6.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=26/70  Signal level=-84 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:93   Missed beacon:0
```

output of `lspci -nn | grep -i net`

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
```

PS: @Andrea Lazzarotto here is the output: http://www.beetxt.com/Gjz/
Help please

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please post the output of `lspci -nn | grep -i net`. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks and here is the output:

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)

Comment: Please try the solution provided here for a similar model and report if it worked: https://askubuntu.com/a/878495/271

Comment: If the suggestion above does not work, please follow this guide and include the output of the *wireless script* in your question: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=13024222

Comment: Didn't work, by the way I tried to run Ubuntu with a LiveUSB and I had the same problem, so I am assuming it's a hardware issue

Comment: Ok thank you, I just added the script in the question

Comment: You need to run the script and then post its output. You posted the source code itself. :P

Comment: Ugh haha, I corrected it lol but it's too long to put in the question so I put it in an external link: http://www.beetxt.com/Gjz/ thanks

Comment: So you confirm you already tried `sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop` and it didn't change the signal quality?

Comment: Yup it didn't do anything